# Determine whether a recursively defined sequence is convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus

$a_1= 1$, $a_{n+1} = 7-a_n$,  for $n$ greater than or equal to $1$.

I know that with the ratio test we have to see if the sequence is decreasing plus if the limit is equal to 0. So would we turn an+1= 7-an into 7/an to make it a ratio?

Comment: You are confusing sequence (which is what you have) with series (which is what the ratio test is for).

Comment: As a sequence, just compute a few terms, and you will see what is happening.

Comment: Also, see how I have edited the math to make it look nicer; see whether you can do the same for the parts I left ugly.

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, consider accepting the answer. That's how the site works. If it is not what you needed, please explain what is still left unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the ratio test works on series, not on sequences. In other words, the ratio test helps you to determine whether an infinite sum, such as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ exists, **not** whether a limit, such as $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$ exists.

---

Second of all, in your case, here is a hint to help you solve it:

> Try and calculate $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$. Can you notice a pattern?

Comment: Is this correct?:  a1=1, a2=6, a3=5, a4=4, a5=3

Comment: Also, to check if it converges or diverges I would have to see if the limit as n goes to infinity exists (converting) or does not exist (diverging) right? But in this case what do I take the limit of, since the sequence given is an+1=7−an, how do we take the limit of this?

Comment: So for my final answer, I got that the sequence is divergent because as n is increasing, an is decreasing without a bound which means the limit of an as n approaches infinity = -infinity. So the sequence is divergent. Is this correct?

Comment: @user1090471 How did you get $a_3=5$?

Comment: an+1=7-an, so in a3, an +1 -> a2+1 -> 7-2 =5

Comment: $a_{n+1}=7-a_n$; when $n=2$, you get $a_3=7-a_2=7-6=1$, user1090471.

Comment: Oh I see so the pattern of the first few terms is 1, 6, 1, 6, 1... Does this mean the sequence diverges since it is not going towards one specific value? Or can I say that it converges to both values of 1 and 6?

Comment: @user1090471 Look at the definition of convergence in any textbook that covers limits. Is there any mention of the possibility of a sequence converging to two values?

Comment: No there isn't. Thank you